# Need help explaining vandermonde's identity combinatorially.

Tags: combinatorics

So I am trying to solve this identity, and I have found multiple answers to this, but all the answers are just copy/paste from wikipedia and no explanations are provided as to how to go from one step to another. I am currently stuck at the very beginning of this step:

$$(1+x)^{r+s}=\sum {r+s\choose n}x^n$$

Can someone explain to me how we know and why the variable '$y$' is set to 1 leaving only $x^n$? This is with the binomial theorem by the the way.

Comment: The title should be "Setting one variable to $1$ in the binomial theorem", or similar.  It has nothing to do with Vandermonde's formula as such, or combinatorics.

Answer (score 1):

The binomial theorem states
$$(a+b)^m = \sum_{\ell = 0}^m \binom{m}{\ell} a^\ell b^{m-\ell}.$$

This can be shown by induction on $m$ using the identity $\binom{m}{\ell} + \binom{m}{\ell - 1} = \binom{m+1}{\ell}$.

Now in the above formula choose $b = 1$ and $a = x$ as well as $m = r+s$. Then your formula drops out (if you chance the summation-index $\ell$ to $n$).

You can just set $b=1$ because on your left hand side you have $(1 + x)^{r+s}$. In the sum you then have $b^{m-\ell} = 1^{m-\ell}=1$.

Comment: how does (m,e)+ (m,e-1) = (m=1, e)? How are you adding the coefficients?

Comment: How do we also know to choose b = 1 and a =x...?

Comment: You want the left hand side of the binomial theorem to be identical to the left hand side of you equation. This is achieved by setting $b=1$ and $a=x$. For the binomial coefficients: these are defined by $\binom{m}{\ell} = \frac{m!}{\ell! \cdot (m-\ell)!}$. I do not add the coefficients, I just wanted to give you an idea of the proof of the binomial theorem. If you already know the binomial theorem or are willing to take it on faith, feel free to ignore that part of my answer.